# PDF not getting downloaded in Devices - Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

I'm using angular Ionic & Capacitor 5. I can download the PDF in the browser view but In mobile devices nothing happens.

I've added the necceccary permission in the AndroidMainFest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Below is my code.

```
import { FileOpener } from '@awesome-cordova-plugins/file-opener/ngx';
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file/ngx';

generateInvoice() {
....
    this.pdfObj = pdfMake.createPdf(dd);
    this.downloadPdf();
}

downloadPdf() {
    if (this.plt.is('cordova')) {
      this.pdfObj.getBuffer((buffer) => {
        const blob = new Blob([buffer], { type: 'application/pdf' });
  
        // Save the PDF to the data Directory of our App
        const fileName = 'bill.pdf'; // Replace with your desired file name
        const directory = this.file.dataDirectory;
  
        this.file.writeFile(directory, fileName, blob, { replace: true })
          .then(_ => {
            console.log('File saved successfully at:', directory + fileName);
            // Now you can open the saved PDF using the FileOpener plugin
            this.fileOpener.open(this.file.dataDirectory + 'bill.pdf', 'application/pdf');

          })
          .catch(error => console.error('Error saving file:', error));
      });
    } else {
      // On a browser simply use download!
      this.pdfObj.download();
    }
  }
```